# Removing Words and Word Counting

Tags: python, computer-science, google-colaboratory

I need help removing paragraphs from this text file (https://www.gutenberg.org/files/768/768.txt) on Google Colab. I need the text file to start after “ccx074@pglaf.org”, and end before “END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK WUTHERING HEIGHTS in order to have an accurate total of the word count. I also need help saving the list as a file so that I can get a correct word count. Listed below is the coding that I have so far.

```
# download and installing pyspark in colab
!pip install -q pyspark

# download Wuthering Heights, by Emily Bronte
!wget -q https://www.gutenberg.org/files/768/768.txt

 import os.path
 baseDir = os.path.join('data')
 inputPath = os.path.join('/content/768.txt')
 fileName = os.path.join(baseDir, inputPath)
 with open('/content/768.txt','r') as f:
       for line in f:
       for word in line.split():
       print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to use two `for line in f:` loops within the same `with open(filename) as f:` block -- one for reading lines as far as the start text, and another for reading lines as far as the end text.  If you `break` from the first `for` loop when you find the line matching the start text, then the next `for` loop will continue with the same iterator which means that it will keep reading lines from the position already reached, not start again from the top of the file.

```
filename = '768.txt'

start_text = 'ccx074@pglaf.org'
end_text = 'END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK WUTHERING HEIGHTS'

with open(filename) as f:

    # skip the header bit
    for line in f:
        if start_text in line:
            break
    else:
        print("end of file reached without seeing the start text")
        
    # count the words - finish when we get to the end line
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        if end_text in line:
            break
        count += len(line.strip().split())
    else:
        print("end of file reached without seeing the end text")

print(count, 'words')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it said that count was not defined.

Comment: Where do you get that error? I am running it on a copy of the file you pointed to, and it counted the words and told me 115899.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are doing exactly, but the `count = 0` in the code I posted is reached unconditionally (provided obviously that nothing before it actually raises an exception e.g. file cannot be read). So even if the start text isn't found and the count doesn't get _incremented_ from 0, at least it should be _defined_.

Comment: Can you help me show the top 15 words used as well and show the words as a list?

Comment: You're may need to ask a separate question for that.  But the `line.strip().split()` is a list of the words read from each line, and you could use the `extend` method of another list to build up a list of all the words, and then use `collections.Counter` to count the occurrences of every word.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.